# Ruby:Capybara:Seleniumで画像がアップロードできない

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

サイト（https://fineuploader.com/demos.html）の一番上段のアップロードフィールドのようなフォームに、画像をアップロードすることができなくて困っています。

クリック自体はできるのですが、次はダイアログの操作方法がわからず、ダイアログを操作してでも、画像をアップロードして解決を図りたいと考えております。

何とかして該当サイトにて画像をアップロードできる方法をご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.app_host = "https://fineuploader.com/demos.html"
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
Capybara.register_driver(:selenium){|app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,:browser => :chrome)
}

class Upload
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    visit("")
  end

  def test_upload
    #クリックすることは可能
    find(:xpath,'//*[@id="fine-uploader-gallery"]/div/div[3]').click
    #画像はアップロードされない
    find(:xpath,'//*[@id="fine-uploader-gallery"]/div/div[3]').set("test.png")
  end
end

upload = Upload.new
upload.test_upload
```

↓スクリーンショット↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ファイルを添付する場合は`attach_file`メソッドを使用します。
そうすればファイル選択ダイアログは出ません。

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions%3Aattach_file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267462/how-to-use-capybara-upload-file